# Is there a function that can create an expanding array formula that conditionally sums a column based on multiple criteria?

Tags: google-sheets

To start, this is my first time posting and so please let me know if I can fix my post in any way to make it easier to answer.

#### I am trying to create an auto-expanding array formula

I have a sheet with my investment asset mix that including amounts of shares owned of each particular stock, and a sheet that tracks when I receive dividends. My goal is to write an automatically expanding array formula that will sum up the amount of shares that own of a stock on the date a dividend is received and return that value. I have written three different formulas that all accomplish this but none of them will auto-expand as an array.

I'm sure there are a lot of solutions I've overlooked. To boil it down, I need an expanding array formula that will sum the "Shares" column of my asset mix sheet ('Asset Mix'!D2:D, or 'AssetMixShares') conditionally. The name of the stock entered in 'Dividends'!C2:C needs to match the name of the stock in 'Asset Mix'!A2:A (or the named range 'AssetMixStocks'). It then needs to check the dates in 'Asset Mix'!C2:C (or 'AssetMixDates') against the dates in 'Dividends'!A2:A and sum all share amounts where the purchase date is less than (earlier than) the Ex-Dividend Date.

I could probably write some sort of vlookup array on the "Running Total" column -- 'Asset Mix'!E:E -- that would solve the issue, but I'm hoping to eliminate that column. I feel very strongly that what I'm trying to do should be possible without the help of a running total column -- I just don't have the knowledge.

I have tried countless functions and formulas, but the four that I currently have in my example worksheet are **SUM**, **SUMPRODUCT**, **DSUM**, and **QUERY**.

#### Attempt 1

**SUM** and **IF**

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF('Asset Mix'!A:A=C2,IF('Asset Mix'!C:C<A2,'Asset Mix'!D:D))))
```

#### Attempt 2

**SUMPRODUCT**

```
=({arrayformula(SUMPRODUCT(--((AssetMixStock=(indirect("C"&ROW())))*(AssetMixDate<(indirect("A"&ROW())))),AssetMixShares))})
```

#### Attempt 3

**DSUM**

```
=DSUM('Asset Mix'!A:E,"Shares",{"Date","Stock";"<"&A2,C2})
```

#### Attempt 4

**QUERY**

```
=arrayformula(query(AssetMix,"Select sum(D) where A = '"&C2:C&"' and C < date'"&(text(year(A2:A),"0000") & "-" & text(month(A2:A),"00") & "-" & text(day(A2:A),"00"))&"' label sum(D) ''",0))
```

These will all work, as long as I manually drag the formula down, but I want to write some sort of formula that will auto-expand to the bottom of the Dividends sheet.

I have tried to create a Dummy sheet that has both of the relevant sheets. Please let me know if you can access it -- the link is below.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wlKffma0NJ0KrlWxyX_N20y62azsGpFp3enhmjzJK1Q/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks so much for getting this far and any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's solved! I'll leave this up in case anyone else has the same question.

A kind soul explained the magic of MMULT() to me, and wrote this solution.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT((C2:C=TRANSPOSE('Asset Mix'!A2:A))*(A2:A>TRANSPOSE('Asset Mix'!C2:C)),N('Asset Mix'!D2:D))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can focus in the first formula to understand a way to make it "self-expandable". As we see it contains references to the cells A2 and C2 in "Dividends" sheet:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF('Asset Mix'!A:A=C2,IF('Asset Mix'!C:C<A2,'Asset Mix'!D:D))))
```

Every time some data appears in these columns (A and C), the formula should work. We can control the presence of the formula by [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite), if editing is manual. Consider the code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Dividends') {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    for (var offset = 0; offset < e.range.getHeight(); offset++) {
      sheet.getRange(3, 10).copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + offset, 10));
    }
  }
}
```

It checks any modification on the sheet "Dividends" and copies required formula to the modified row(s). This way the formula is expanded for other rows in use.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The reason I haven't turned to writing code to solve the issue is that I'm worried that additional code will bloat my spreadsheet. I've been favoring array formulas because they seem to create less calculation time for my spreadsheet. I have two macros that have periodic triggers to grab info off of the internet and it's a fairly large spreadsheet so things are pretty slow as is, hence me looking for a way to write the formula as an array formula that auto-expands.